# RedMine how to configure an issue section with 4 columns of checkboxes instead of the 2 column default?

Tags: plugins, configuration, redmine

I want issues in RedMine to be defined better via a block of checkboxes. RedMine configuration for issues defaults to 2 columns as shown in **(A)** below.

I want to add a custom issues section similar to how the "Watchers" section appears (see **(B)** below) as 4 columns as a block of checkboxes that I define:

- blue screen [ ], logs uploaded [ ], failed in lab [ ], failed
  in the field [ ], machine was idle [ ], machine was busy [ ], after
  hours [ ], one time failure [ ], re-creatable [ ], test case 1 [ ],
  test case 2 [ ], loss of data [ ], reboot required [ ], etc.

Another way to asked this is to say how can I create my own issues section that has checkboxes in 4 columns similar to the Watchers issues section is formatted?

And while seeking RedMine enhancement guidance, it would also be useful to have one checkbox dynamically expand into a group of checkboxes. Can this be done?

**(A) - shows the default 2 columns**

[image: new issue block of checkboxes default 2 colums]

**(B) - make issues section w/ 4 columns, similar to the Watchers section**

[image: whatcher checkboxes in columns of 4]